# Why can't I move the cursor to a new row when I insert '\n' at the end of a text with javascript?

Tags: javascript, newline

Using this function:

```
function insertTextAtCursor(text) {
    var sel, range, html;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode( document.createTextNode(text) );
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().text = text;
    }
}
```

Like this:

```
insertTextAtCursor('\n');
```

I add a new line into a `<div contenteditable=true></div>`

Afterwards I would expect that I could push the right arrow on my keyboard to move to a new line. I can't however. If I add another newline I can move to that row. It's only the last new line that I can't move to.

If I start writing on the second to last newline, the last newline disappears.

It feels like I don't understand how newline behaves when it's the last character in a string. How can I make it so that I can move to that row of the document?

Comment: I've noticed this glitch in just normal textareas, no JavaScript at all, but I can't produce it consistently so for now I just type some letters and keep trying until it lets me get at the last line XD Sorry this isn't very helpful...

Comment: I disagree, very helpful! Is this textareas in any particular browsers?

Comment: try to add <div/> instead of \n

Comment: But I need it to be a \n. <div/> works.